# How to explain the different tenses here?

Tags: tense, spoken-english, reported-speech, informal-language

I'm doing TOEFL speaking practice, and today I met something I can't explain in TPO15: the girl is in the choir where everyone is asked to wear a white shirt and black pants. But she just spilled spaghetti sauce all over it. Here's what she's saying:

> I just **called** the choir director, and he **is** obviously unhappy about all this. But I **told** him about another shirt I have. It's not exactly white, not white like the others, sort of off-white, sort of cream-colored? And he **says** it's okay for me to wear it.

I don't understand the different tenses used in this paragraph. It should be either all past tenses or all present tenses. So what's going on here?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried searching about this?

Comment: Does TOEFL require you to explain tenses? This is informal speech. The director remains unhappy, thus he is unhappy. His permission to wear the off-white blouse could be either tense (the phone call is past; the permission is ongoing).

Comment: No, I don't need to explain these. But I do use these materials to improve my English since they're really good and idiomatic. So I take care of every detail of these sentences. And these changes in tenses don't make sense to me.

Comment: This is informal speech. As Xanne says, the phone call is in the past (_called, told_), the conductor's unhappiness is ongoing (_is_). She could have said "He said that it would be OK for me to wear it", but in casual speech we often use the present tense for reporting other people's statements or opinions that are still true - "Jim says he is coming to the party tomorrow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reporting speech informally, it's common to use present tense to report things *which are still true now*.

In this case, the conductor *is* unhappy and it *is* OK for her to wear the off-white shirt.

The narrator could have told the story like this:

> ... and he **was** obviously unhappy about all this ... and he **said** it's okay for me to wear it

This way is only a report of what the conductor said, which only tells us what the conductor felt at the time of the call, not what is true now. The way the narrator tells the story, including present tenses, tells us more about the situation.

Comment: I must add that this use is also common in journalism. For example, **Party officials say they will announce the timetable for a leadership election by Monday. [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/07/07/europe/boris-johnson-resignation-intl/index.html)** Members on this forum frequently denigrate journalism, but it *is* usually edited (unlike a conversation or a tweet) and accounts for a large percentage of regularly published text. I therefore suggest that the formal-informal distinction is not clear-cut in this case.